# Get sanitized parameter from processAction - Liferay

Tags: java, servlets, liferay, xss

I have to implement a filter to prevent XSS attack in my Liferay Portal. I have read a lot of answers about it, so I used an HttpServletRequestWrapper to add sanitized parameters to my request. My filter works properly: debugging the code I realized that the filter takes the parameter and sanitized it. 
My problem is that in the processAction of a portlet I am not able to retrieve the sanitized parameter using request.getParameter() but I always get the old not sanitized parameter.

For example, suppose I have a portlet with a simple form like this:

[image]

As you can see in the input field there is a *b* tag to sanitize. When the form is submitted my filter is invoked and it throws the doFilter() method. 
My doFilter method iterates over all parametes doing sanitation. Then I add them in my WrappedRequest:

```
    /*
     * Did it make any difference?
     */
    if (!Arrays.equals(processedParams, params)) {
        logger.info("Parameter: " + params[0] + " sanitized with: " + processedParams[0] );
        /*
         * If so, wrap up the request with a new version that will return the trimmed version of the param
         */
        HashMap<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(name, processedParams);
        final HttpServletRequestWrapper newRequest = new ExtendedRequestWrapper(httpServletRequest,map);                    


        /*
         * Return the wrapped request and forward the processing instruction from
         * the validation rule
         */
        return newRequest;
```

My class ExtendedRequestWrapper implements getparameter method:

```
public class ExtendedRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private final Map<String, String[]> modifiableParameters;
    private Map<String, String[]> allParameters = null;


    public ExtendedRequestWrapper(final HttpServletRequest request, 
            final Map<String, String[]> additionalParams)
    {
        super(request);
        this.modifiableParameters = new TreeMap<String, String[]>();
        this.modifiableParameters.putAll(additionalParams);
    }

    @Override
    public String getParameter(final String name)
    {
        String[] strings = getParameterMap().get(name);
        if (strings != null)
        {
            return strings[0];
        }
        return super.getParameter(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap()
    {
        if (this.allParameters == null)
        {
            this.allParameters = new TreeMap<String, String[]>();
            this.allParameters.putAll(super.getParameterMap());
            this.allParameters.putAll(modifiableParameters);

        }
        //Return an unmodifiable collection because we need to uphold the interface contract.
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(allParameters);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getParameterNames()
    {
        return Collections.enumeration(getParameterMap().keySet());
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getParameterValues(final String name)
    {
        return getParameterMap().get(name);
    }
}
```

Now, when I try to access to sanitized params in my processAction() I get the old value, that one not sanitized:

```
  @Override
public void processAction(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) throws PortletException, IOException {
    String azione = request.getParameter("MyXSSaction");
    if(azione.equals("XSSAttack")) {        
    String descr = req.getParameter("mydescr");
    }
}
```

How can I solve?

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this generically in your input handling. First of all, there is no XSS in `<b>`, as the second S in XSS is for 'scripting' - and `<b>` doesn't contain any scripts.

Second, a general and thorough application of such a filter will effectively keep you from adding proper web content, blog articles and other content, where formatting is legitimately done.

Third - let's say you have a random book management system: Why shouldn't people be able to enter `Let x < 5` as a book title, or even `<script>alert('XSS')</script> and what to do against it` - wouldn't they be proper book titles? In fact, they'd be proper data, and you want to escape them when you display.

There might be an argument for sanitizing (like Liferay's AntiSamy plugin does) certain elements if they're meant to be displayed as HTML. But anything else just needs to be properly escaped during output.

Another way to put it: Those parameters are only dangerous if you incorrectly don't escape them when they're shown in HTML pages - but if you embed them in a text/plain email body, they're completely harmless.